# If I have a Stripe token from a charge, how do I get its charge id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Right now I'm making successful charges with my Rails app but I'd like to to fetch certain details about the transaction such as the description of the item purchase and the last four digits of the credit card to show the user on their receipt page.

I've been looking at the documentation but there's really nothing that explains how to give an app the token and get back the charge_id which I can then use to get a hash of other info about the charge.

Any help would be huge. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a few code snippets which might give a better idea of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 6):

Stripe returns charge IDs in the response to a charge creation call. If you're using the Ruby library, you can do something like this to get the ID:

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = '<your api key>'
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
  :amount => 400,
  :currency => "usd",
  :card => "tok_JkdcRcQfyFsoZ2", # obtained with Stripe.js
  :description => "Charge for test@example.com"
)
```

You can then store `charge.id` and use the [Charge Retrieve call](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_charge) to look up charge details.

Comment: **This doesn't seem like an answer**. Creating a new charge doesn't help resolve a token back to a charge, it creates a new charge. In most cases where somebody needs to look up an associated charge from a token, the token would have already been used, and hence can't create a new charge.

Answer (score 0):

Dexter at Stripe just confirmed:

> Unfortunately at this time there is not a way to get a charge from a token.

**A workaround**: if you have a timestamp of the token, you can use it to find the charge.