# How to get charge id after creating a subscription using Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using `Stripe` as a payment gateway. Now there's a big problem bothers me.

I used code below to create a subscription:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/Stripe.php');

Stripe::setApiKey(API_KEY);

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    "card"  => $token,
    "plan"  => $_POST['plan'],
    "email" => "fakeuser@gmail.com",
));
```

This works fine, but I can not get `Charge ID` from `$customer`, and I found out there's no way in `Stripe API` to get it.

How to get it when creating a subscription? I really need `Charge ID`.

Comment: You get the charge ID in response to a charge creation request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031063/if-i-have-a-stripe-token-from-a-charge-how-do-i-get-its-charge-id

Comment: @Anigel I don't understand. The code I provided has already made a charge, why should I make another charge request?

Comment: You shouldn't, but when you made the charge was when you got the charge_id

Comment: Anigel - he means (I think) for a _subscription_, how does he get a charge ID each time a charge is made? Or is that not it, davidx?

Comment: You are right, Robert! The problem is very clear: I create a subscription and I want to get charge ID from it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is exactly what [Stripe's webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) are for. After creating a customer with an initial subscription, you'll get six webhook notifications:

1. `customer.created`, with the customer data (which you already have if you're saving what the API returns)
2. **`charge.succeeded`** (or `charge.failed`), **which contains the initial charge data you're looking for**
3. `invoice.created`, which is the associated invoice
4. `invoice.payment_succeeded` (or `invoice.payment_failed`), also telling you the status of the charge
5. `customer.card.created`, with the details of the new card
6. `customer.subscription.created`, with the details of the customer's subscription.

Stripe's API, like many APIs and many payment solutions, is built to be used with webhooks. If you're not taking advantage of webhooks, you're going to be missing functionality, and you're probably working too hard for what can be done without webhooks.

Stripe works to deliver the data to you. If you're writing code to poll Stripe, you're working way, way too hard.

Comment: Thank you, @colinm. I use same way you suggested, and I think it's the only way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: seems like the webhook callback for charge.succeeded does not contain a subscription_id like the other notifications do. How do you link the charge.succeeded call with the original subscription without having to do a join on card and and customer since these aren't guaranteed unique?

Comment: Using `invoice.payment_succeeded` for that seems to be a much better option. It contains a subscription ID, a customer ID and a charge ID (if there was indeed a charge). AFAIK `charge.succeeded` won't be fired if someone downgraded the subscription and has enough account balance to pay for the next period.

Comment: When `invoice.payment_succeeded` event has been fired, does this mean that the charge has gone through? I'm not sure if i have to listen for both this event and `charge.succeeded` to confirm the payment has gone through?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same issue myself.  I'm using the python library but the answer is more about Stripe's API than what language the client is in.

Ultimately, since I'm creating a new customer with each subscription, I was able to look up the invoice against the customer_id and grab its charge id.  Here's what the python code for that looks like:

```
stripe_api.Invoice.all(customer=subscribe_result['customer'])['data'][0]['charge']
```

Again, note that this method would not work if you re-use customers, only if creating new customers with each subscription create.

It's certainly not ideal.  It would be far better if the charge id were included in the return.  Even knowing the Invoice ID would at least solve the issue of re-using customers though it would still require an unnecessary API call to fetch the invoice.

Comment: Invoices are guaranteed to be returned in order, newest first. You can make Stripe do the heavy lifting on that one by passing `count=1` along with the Customer ID.

Comment: Considering that Strip creates the Charge before the Invoice (subscription) then they have no reason no to include the chargeId when creating the subscription object. I too had to use a unique customer object per subscription to get around this problem.

Comment: @geo1701: why is it a requirement to use a unique customer object? Won't it still be the most recent invoice for the customer used anyway?

Comment: Superb, i'm absolutely lazier than you :D

Answer (score 4):

Another option you can use if you need the charge id right away and can't wait for a webhook is use the `latest_invoice` field on the returned subscription object.

A python example:

```py
inv_id = subscription.latest_invoice
inv = stripe.Invoice.retrieve(inv_id)
charge_id = inv.charge
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no straight-forward way to do this. There is however a hack to get `charge_id` for that `subscription` with out waiting for `invoice.payment_succeeded` `callback`.

This how I did in `Ruby`, you can treat this as a `pseudo` code. May be you can do this using `PHP` `API`s

```
  # Lets not retrieve all the invoices
  #  use filter
  lower_limit_date = DateTime.strptime(that_subscription.start.to_s, '%s') - 1.hour
  upper_limit_date = 2.hours.from_now

  list_object_of_all_invoices_in_range = Stripe::Invoice.all(
      {
          customer: customer_id,
          date: {
              gt: lower_limit_date.to_i, # Start TimeStamp
              lt: upper_limit_date.to_i # End TimeStamp
          }
      })

  particular_invoice = list_object_of_all_invoices_in_range.data.
      keep_if { |s| s[:subscription] == that_subscription.id }.first

  stripe_charge_id = particular_invoice.charge # gives charge_id
```

[See structure of `ListObject` for `Invoices`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_invoices)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while searching for how to extract subscription ID in Java. Turns out the new version of the API (1.7.1 for Java) has ID field built right into the subscription object. The same is probably true for the PHP API.

Comment: the actual question was not about the subscription ID, it was about the charge ID, thus your answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck over the same problem after spending some time it turns out to be pretty simple.

Step 1: Call *retrieve all invoice* API with *subscription id* as a parameter.

Example in PHP:

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("subscription" => your_subscription_id));
```

In `$invoice` you will get Charge ID and hence, you can get everything after that.