# Retrieve a stripe charge having customer id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

If I have a customer id `cus_jkhjsa776757`, is it possible to retrieve a charge associated with that customer id? For example, something like:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve({ :id => 'cus_jkhjsa776757' })
```

For that I am getting an error:

> "Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such charge: cus_jkhjsa776757)"

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. Any input on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one it should return charges for the customer specified by this customer ID.

In [DOCs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges)

[image]

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.list(customer: "cus_jkhjsa776757")
```

Also good source for you:
[How to get charge id after creating a subscription using Stripe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338935/how-to-get-charge-id-after-creating-a-subscription-using-stripe#answer-18678296)